# Mutual induction in electromagnetic wave theory

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

Frequently when electromagnetic waves are taught, it is said that the change in electric field causes a change in the magnetic field, which then causes a change in the electric field, and so on and so forth.

There is an ongoing discussion on Physics Stack Exchange of how (far) this is true (see: [Do the electric and magnetic components of an electromagnetic wave really generate each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/181277/do-the-electric-and-magnetic-components-of-an-electromagnetic-wave-really-genera) or [How can one meaningfully say that one field generates the other in an EM-wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228796/how-can-one-meaningfull-say-that-one-field-generates-the-other-in-an-em-wave)). However, in this question, I am interested in the historic point of view about this.

Are there passages in the papers or books of the founding fathers of the electromagnetic theory (Maxwell, Hertz, ...) which express this statement (in words, not formulas) and, even further, use it as a main idea in developing the theory?